# Adjusting effect sizes, p values, and CIs for sequential analysis via simulation

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, simulation, effect-size, sequential-analysis

It's fairly easy to write a simulation procedure to calculate, for any given global type 1 error rate, adjusted local "stopping" alphas for interim "looks" in a [sequential design](https://psyarxiv.com/x4azm/), for any sort of significance test. Basically I simulate the observations, and do the tests as I would in a real experiment by continually adding observations until I get a significant outcome at an interim look or reach the final look.

My problem and the question is: **How can I correct effect sizes, p values, and CIs, in a way that is generalizable to any conventional significance test?** I'd guess it should again be some sort of simulation procedure, but of course I'd just as well welcome any other solution.

I do have a vague idea for correcting standardized effect sizes: having obtained, in my real experiment, the given effect size and p value, I could simulate again a bunch of effect size variations to find the "true" (simulated) effect size with which it is most likely that, in my sequential analysis, I end up with the obtained effect size and/or p value. However, even in that case I would not know what specific data characteristic contributed to the effect size difference, i.e., for example, in case of a t-test, I wouldn't know whether in the real standardized effect size (Cohen's d) the variance is smaller or the mean difference is larger. But maybe that's simply impossible to tell?

As for adjusting p values, my intuition is that I could repeat the simulation procedure with the obtained p value as local alpha at the given "look", and leaving all other settings unchanged. Then the resulting global type 1 error rate could be the adjusted p value. (The CI could then also be derived in a similar manner.) But I'm really not sure whether this would be correct.

(Note: I'm aware that there are solutions for certain basic parametric tests, like t-tests, in `rpact`, `gsDesign`, etc., but I want the procedure to be generalizable to any sort of statistical significance test.)